# Inserting heavy objects into std::map

Tags: c++, performance, containers, stdmap, std

How many times exactly copies the `VeryHeavy(args...)` in this code?

```
map.emplace(std::pair<VeryHeavyKey, VeryHeavy>(key, VeryHeavy(args...)));
```

Or, maybe, there is better to use `std::make_pair`?
Are there any standartized warranties on copying objects? What's the right way to insert heavy objects into std::map without copying?

Comment: How about a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: I don't understand, where should I use `shared_ptr`?

Comment: `map.emplace(std::move(key), VeryHeavy(args...));` seems like an improvement. I would expect zero copies from that code.

Comment: What makes `std::move(...)`?

Comment: I assume you already has many `VeryHeavy` and need to put them in a map. My suggestion is replacing `VeryHeave` with shared_ptr. Depends on what you "don't" want to be copied. I might interpret your question in a wrong way.

Comment: `std::move` is defined in `#include <utility>` is that what you mean?

Comment: @LouisGo In the main, I'm asking about warranties that compilator will optimize this copying and will construct `VeryHeavy` straight in right place.

Comment: Declaration of std::make_pair uses perfect forwarding, and I hope that it is guaranteed that compilator will optimize the `VeryHeavy(args...)` rvalue. (And I don't want to corrupt code's clarity and structure by using `shared_ptr`.)

Comment: Standard is C++ 17, `VeryHeavy` isn't movable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What's the right way to insert heavy object into std::map without copying?

prior to C++17

```
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
              std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(key)),
              std::forward_as_tuple(args...));
```

post C++17

```
map.try_emplace(std::move(key), args...);
```

The C++17 variant improves on the former by not constructing a `VeryHeavy` if `key` is already present.